# Link To Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded an Event that links to a website when a range is selected:

```
    If Selection.Name = Range("D2").Value Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.google.com", _
        NewWindow:=True
    End If
```

How do I direct the link to a different worksheet within the active workbook? I have tried modifying the Address to:

```
Address:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
```

However this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: also try `Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")`

Comment: Thanks @Simoco - this works! If you add this as an answer I am happy to add to your reputation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use:

```
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

or, if you still want to use `FollowHyperlink` method:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .FollowHyperlink Address:=.Name, _
                     SubAddress:=.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Address(External:=True)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the sheet, then the desired range;

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Select
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexK - although how do I incorporate this into the Address of the Hyperlink?